# Loading of Image in Graphics View

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I want to load the image in Graphics View by making its different class, so that it can be treated as entity and all the operations like undo, redo, cut, copy and paste can be applied on it. Other entities which I am having are point, Line, circle, ellipse etc. Each entity has its own class. Please provide me the path to proceed for the above.

Comment: I am not getting how to proceed by making of class earlier I did it using a slot in which code to load an image was written but now as it has to treated as entity so how to proceed with it.

Comment: Inherit QGraphicsItem and add your own handling on how the entity should behave. [Check Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html). Hope this is what you want.